# Add in for Outlook 2016 not running

Tags: visual-studio, outlook

I am developing a simple add in for Outlook 2016, using Visual Studio 2017. I have created a simple ribbon with one group and one simple button calling a Message.Show() to test it.

The thing is that the ribbon doesn't show in my Outlook when I start the program. I already changed the RibbonType property to Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer as someone mentioned, but the ribbon just doesn't show.

Any hint that I can use to solve this question?

I was trying to build an Excel Add In just to check if the behaviour was the same but I get an error - "The file '' does not support code parsing or generation because it is not contained within a project that supports code".

Thanks guys.

Bruno.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsFej.png)

Comment: Have you tried **File > Options > Customize Ribbon** and import your ribbon from the **Import/Export** button in the bottom right of the window?

Comment: I have tried that but the project did not generate any exportUI file.

Comment: How did you create your ribbon? By code? If yes, could you post it

Comment: I have created it in design as documented in the screenshot I've added to the post.

Comment: My AddIns ribbon is selected in "Customize Ribbon" but does not appear on my menu. Is this normal?

Comment: This will only enable the Add-ins tab in the ribbon. I found [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-export-a-ribbon-from-the-ribbon-designer-to-ribbon-xml?view=vs-2017) on Microsoft documentation, maybe this will help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was Outlook's version. After reinstalling it is working fine.